# Django 1.8: Model doesn't appear in admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am following Django official tutorial and I got stuck at [the second part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/). In particular, I can't have my newly created model displayed in the admin panel. Step by step:

1. I created a new app;
2. I add it to settings.py (see below);
3. I edited the models.py file (see below);
4. I ran my first migration, succesfully;
5. (I check on MySQL and everything was created ok);
6. I change the admin.py file (see below);
7. I refreshed maniacally the admin panel with no results.

myproject/myproject/**settings.py**:

```
[...]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
)

[...]
```

myproject/myapp/**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models 

class Question(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

myproject/myapp/**admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? Have you tried killing it and starting again? Also check if there are no WSGI processes stucked in background.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Me feeling very stupid. :) I restarted my Apache server and now I can see the Question model in the Admin panel!

Comment: what is the admin URL you are trying. Looks like you have already navigated into the authentication app.

Answer (score 1):

How do you start the debug-server? Did it restarts after your changing the code? Try to stop the debug server and start over again with --nothreading option.

Comment: I am not using a debug server. I deployed on Apache using wsgi_mod.

Comment: Don't do that. When you're starting out, use the dev server; it'll save you lots of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Role

class RoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Role

admin.site.register(Role,RoleAdmin)
```

Does it make sense for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try killing or restarting your WSGI server. Also check if there are no WSGI processes stucked in background.